# XSL generates cascading XHTML tags instead of start-end-tags

Tags: xslt

I wanted to parse XML to XHTML (XHTML because of the self-closing tags) and after I switched from output method `html` to `xml` the output was pure chaos.

XML

```
<a>
  <b>test</b>
  <b>test</b>
  <b>test</b>
</a>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:for-each select="a/b">
  <div><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Expected XHMLT (this is the result with output method `html`)

```
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

Actual result:

```
<div>test
     <div>test
          <div>test</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am completely lost at this.

Comment: Please post a complete stylesheet. The part that you show us does NOT produce the result you claim.

Comment: Sure the stylesheet is bigger, MUCH bigger, but it only conatins ´for-each´ ´choose´ and ´if´ nothing else. Parsing this as `html` works perfectly but parsing as `xml` screws everything up so there must be something different between the output methodes ´html´ and ´xml´.

Comment: As I said, the problem cannot be reproduced using your code. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have shown us, so you need to show us more. Try to construct a minimal but runnable example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Okay now I know what COULD be wrong: the xhtml file is well formatted, but the browser reads the file wrong? so the "actual result" code is only present in the browser (in the source code the browser shows). I will try it with Apache Xalan instead of Oracle XDK ...